# How to delete row using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using PHP to display what is in my MySQL database in a table. I think it is working but the output is still "ERROR". I need to delete all records in a row.

```
<?php
require_once ('config.inc.php');
$id=$_POST['id'];
$sql = "DELETE `subject_information` WHERE `id`='$id'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if ($result)
{
    echo "Deleted Successfully";
}
else
{
    echo "ERROR!";
    mysql_close();
}
?>
```

Comment: `DELETE FROM ...`

Comment: Try this tutorial => http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_delete.asp

Comment: Thanks. my syntax is wrong.

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` functions because are deprecated and will be removed in future versions, check `mysqli` functions  or `PDO`

Comment: Your code currently has SQL injection vulnerabilities - your application can be easily hacked if you put this live. At the very least, escape or cast user input prior to injecting it into a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot your `FROM` keyword. The proper syntax is:

```
DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE some_column=some_value;
```

So your code should be like this:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM `subject_information` WHERE `id`='$id'";
```

Comment: You forgot your FROM?  add explanation

Answer (score 0):

you should change this line :

```
$sql = "DELETE `subject_information` WHERE `id`='$id'";
```

to

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM `subject_information` WHERE `id`='".$id."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should output the error that is returned from the database:

```
if ($result)
{
    echo "Deleted Successfully";
}
else
{
    echo mysql_error();
}
```

Second: the mysql_xxxx functions will be removed from PHP in future version. You should have a look at PDO to connect to your database

Answer (score 0):

Syntax of your query has to be changed for deleting a row from table use following syntax

$sql = "DELETE FROM tablename WHERE `id`='$id'";

Answer (score 0):

off topic, but please read http://php.net/manual/security.database.sql-injection.php

this type of query is vulnerable for SQL-Injections, because you don't check/quote your $id.

As a hint, these functions may help you:

- mysql_real_escape_string
- ctype_digit
- is_numeric

Comment: You should've posted that as a comment.

Comment: I am new here at stack. Prior to that post i was not allowed to write comments.